# How do I remove the all the spaces in the end result?

Tags: python

How do I remove the all the spaces in the end result?

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 
'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 
'Y', 'Z']

numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

x_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your 
password? "))

x_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like? "))

x_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like? "))


import random

password_list = []

for char in range(1, x_letters + 1):
    password_list.append(random.choice(letters))

for char in range(1, x_symbols + 1):
    password_list.append(random.choice(numbers))

for char in range(1, x_numbers + 1):
    password_list.append(random.choice(symbols))

random.shuffle(password_list)

print(" ".join(password_list))
```

When I input everything it types everything like this:

```
r 3 a $ w & % 6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Last line should be

```
print("".join(password_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave no space in the join method attachment
which is print("".join(password_list))
Anything within that string will separate the elements

Comment: To improve your code, don't list the alphabets and numbers when randomizing. Import the string class and call the string.digits for numbers, string.ascii_letters for letters and string.punctuation for symbols